# Programmatically Execute Cell Jupyter VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am looking for a way to programmatically replicate the Run Cell Below functionality VS code.

Previously, I used Jupyter through Conda and used the following code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display,Markdown,Javascript,HTML

def run_below(ev):
    Javascript('IPython.notebook.execute_cells_below()')
    
button = widgets.Button(description="Click to run cells below")
button.on_click(run_below)
display(button)
```

This code worked great, but when I tried to plop it into VSCode, the button just does nothing. I don't understand much about how the VSCode Jupyter backend works, but I'm imagining it has something do do with the IPython.notebook module not working correctly in this IDE (or perhaps the IPython.display.Javascript module?). I really have no real idea though.

**Does anyone know how I could do this in VSCode's Jupyter implementation?**

I have searched for hours on this topic, but have not been able to find a working solution that works. Please let me know if y'all have any ideas.

> Environment Info:
>
> > Python Version: 3.9.12 
> > VSCode Version: 1.69.0 
> > Jupyter Extension Version: v2022.6.1001902341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the ability to access the Kernel in VS code is not possible at this time. See the following GitHub issues to see if this has changed at the time of reading:

[Similar question migrated to #6918](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7551)

[Issue #6918 that will resolve problem once closed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6918)

Comment: Issue #6918 is closed but this still does not work. Any ideas how to get this to work now that #6918 is closed?

Comment: @user15420598 I saw it was closed but I have no idea what Don Jayamanne is saying there in terms of how it can now be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to detailed question but is an answer to the title of the question "Programmatically execute cell jupyter vscode" since I landed on this page searching for how to do this. The following code supports this task - just make sure to hit save CTRL-S if you make changes to cells that are going to be run by the following function since it reads the current version of file from disk

```
def execute_cell(filepath,cell_number_range=[0]):
    import io
    from  nbformat import current

    with io.open(filepath) as f:
        nb = current.read(f, 'json')
    ip = get_ipython()
    for cell_number in cell_number_range:
        cell=nb.worksheets[0].cells[cell_number]
        #print (cell)
        if cell.cell_type == 'code' : ip.run_cell(cell.input)
```

also for finding name of current notebook in vscode is easy but not easy in jupyterlab

```
import os
globals()['__vsc_ipynb_file__'] #full name only in vscode
os.path.basename(globals()['__vsc_ipynb_file__']) #basename only in vscode . globals()['_dh'] #dir in most
```

Comment: This works but not in the way that I was asking. This will execute a range of cells and output to the current cell's output (the cell where execute_cell was run). What I am looking for is a way to actually tie in the execution of cells to code using a button.